# convert two loops over two dimensional array to Linq syntax

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a two dimensional array containing objects of type `MyObj`.

```
private MyObj[,] myObjs = new MyObj[maxX, maxY];
```

I want to get the indices from the array when passing in a matching object. I want to get the x and y value from this array. I can return these two values as a `Position` object that takes a x and y coordinate.

```
private Position GetIndices(MyObj obj)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < myObjs.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < myObjs.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (myObjs[x, y] == obj)
            {
                return new Position(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get this code shorten to some Linq code lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But I don't think, it looks nice :)

```
        var result = Enumerable.Range(0, myObjs.GetLength(0))
            .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, myObjs.GetLength(1)).Select(y => new { x, y }))
            .SelectMany(o => o)
            .FirstOrDefault(o => myObjs[o.x, o.y] == obj);
```

Comment: yep, not nice, Traditional For / Foreach is more readable for long run. Linq is spoiling with it's syntactic sugar :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, if you're interested. It uses an indexer inside the first select and does a little math to find where that index falls inside the two-dimensional array.

```
var o = new MyObj();

myObjs[1,2] = o;

var p = myObjs.Cast<MyObj>()
              .Select((x,i) => Tuple.Create(x,i))
              .Where(x => x.Item1 == o)
              .Select(x => new Point(x.Item2 / myObjs.GetLength(1), x.Item2 % myObjs.GetLength(1)))
              .SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(p);  // prints {X=1,Y=2}
```

It sorta looks like you're considering the x-coordinate to be the height of the array, and the y-coordinate the width, in which case you'd want to switch it up slightly:

```
var p = myObjs.Cast<MyObj>()
              .Select((x,i) => Tuple.Create(x,i))
              .Where(x => x.Item1 == o)
              .Select(x => new Point(x.Item2 % myObjs.GetLength(1), x.Item2 / myObjs.GetLength(1)))
              .SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(p);  // prints {X=2,Y=1}
```

I used `Point` instead of `Position` since it's built into .NET but you should be able to just swap one for the other.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is possible. You can ask Resharper to do the job (loop to linq) for you. After installation, [just use the feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/files/2009/12/aggregation_count__action.png).

Comment: This is not the answer, it is just a suggestion to use a tool that would convert this code to linq

Comment: The question was if it os possible. The answer has been given: "Yes". That is the answer. There is also an explanation of how you can do it: ask Resharper. It is not asked how the code should look like.